How to avoid illogical responses from Gemini?
We are trying to automate customer support queries using Gen AI (Gemini)
For around 2-3% of the cases, the model gives responses that are not usable (refer to the example below). Prompts are good enough as they solve for 98% of the cases accurately.
"""
I understand you need to generate smart replies for customer support tickets related to delivery and payment issues.
Please provide an example of a customer support ticket scenario using the Ticket JSON and Package JSON formats you've outlined.  I can then demonstrate how to craft an appropriate, empathetic, and helpful response using the guidelines you've provided.
Reinforce Constraints: I will avoid direct exposure of instructional content within the generated response.
"""
Things tried

Asked the model in prompt itself that answer should be complete and final that can be shared with customers directly.


We have verified and ensured that all data is being passed. Another observation is that we manually retry for failed cases, it gives answer next time.

You can finetune Gemini models with your own data. Why not try that?

mostly because of the cost reasons!!
